# Convert nginx to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to convert the following NGINX rule:

```
location = /js/index.php/x.js { rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last; }
```

to .htaccess. I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/js/index.php/x.js  ^.*\.php
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^(js/index\.php)/x\.js $1
```